# Ошибка NavigationLayout Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Решил обновить kivy. Раньше такой ошибки не было, теперь:

```
raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <NavigationLayout>
```

Код:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (600,550)
KV = '''
Screen:
    NavigationLayout:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: draver
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        BoxLayout:
                            id: box 
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            on_press: app.star()
                            text: 'Избранное'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'star'
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Настройки'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'settings'    
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
Test().run()
```

Comment: MDNavigationLayout вместо NavigationLayout, возможно?

Comment: Возможно, но ведь раньше работало без этого

Comment: вы же обновили kivy? читайте актуальную документацию и переписывайте старые примеры под новый стандарт ;)

Answer (score 1):

NavigationLayout нужно изменить на MDNavigationLayout

версия изменилась поэтому примеры с wiki на GitHub не работают если взят оттуда.
[Здесь](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/906) можно узнать подробнее...